# How to comprehend "Inheritance in C++ is to express interface compliance, not to get code reuse"?Could anybody make it clear by some simple examples?

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

As per the documentation(https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/objective-c#objective-c-and-inherit), which says:

> The purpose of inheritance in C++ is to express interface compliance (subtyping), not to get code reuse. In C++, code reuse usually comes via composition rather than via inheritance. In other words, inheritance is mainly a specification technique rather than an implementation technique.

**How to comprehend it? Could anybody make it clear by some simple examples?**

Comment: Say you have an I/O interface, and have a File I/O implementation.  Years later, someone makes a Cloud I/O implementation.  All the code that uses the I/O interface written years before the cloud existed does not have to change when a Cloud I/O object is used for reading & writing the information.  That's code reuse, by keeping the I/O part abstract from the users of the I/O interface.

Comment: @Eljay As the example forementioned in your comment, it makes me sense that "code reuse" is same with "interface compliance".But the documentation says: "The purpose of inheritance is not to get code reuse".

Comment: That is in the context of "I have a class Foo.  And now I need a class Bar which is 80% just like class Foo, but a few differences.  Now I have Foo and Bar that gets to reuse all of Foo's methods, adds a few, and changes a few.  Even though Bar can no longer be used as a Foo, because the *callers* of Bar have to change to use the Bar methods."  That violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackify.com/solid-design-liskov-substitution-principle/).  If Bar cannot be substituted for a Foo, then Bar is-not-a Foo.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a (admittedly silly) class named `store_an_int`:

```
class store_an_int {
public:
    store_an_int(int x) : val(x) {}
    void set_my_value(int x) { val = x; }
    int get_my_value() const { return val; }
private:
    int val;
};
```

Now you can store and retrieve an integer value:

```
store_an_int value(3);
std::cout << value.get_my_value(); // displays "3"
value.set_my_value(4);
std::cout << value.get_my_value(); // displays "4"
```

Now you have a class that needs to store an int and do some work on it. You could write it like this:

```
class doubler : public store_an_int {
public:
    doubler(int x) : store_an_int(x) {}
    int get_my_value() const { return store_an_int::get_my_value() * 2; }
};
```

Now you can store an integer value and retrieve its doubled value:

```
doubler value(3);
std::cout << value.get_my_value(); // displays "6"
value.set_my_value(4);
std::cout << value.get_my_value(); // displays "8"
```

That's code reuse. Yes, `doubler` stores an int value, but that's incidental to what it does, and using inheritance is misleading. `doubler` has two member functions which have the same names as the member functions in `store_an_int`. But what do you want to happen if someone adds a member function to `store_an_int`, let's say, `void store_an_int::show() const { std::cout << val << '\n'; }`? Now `doubler` has a new member function, `show()`, that shows the wrong value. Yes, you could rewrite `doubler` to store the doubled value instead of the raw value, and that would make `store_an_int::show()` show the right value. But if you don't want that function, you're still stuck with it.

Instead, the code should use composition:

```
class doubler {
public:
    doubler(int x) : value(x) {}
    int get_my_value() const { return value.get_my_value() * 2; }
    void store_my_value(int x) { value.store_my_value(x); }
private:
    store_my_value value;
};
```

Now if `store_an_int` adds a member function, it doesn't become part of the interface to `doubler`, and you can simply ignore it.

Comment: Thank you for your attention.What does "interface compliance" mean?How to comprehend it?